# How to make ssh tunneling from google compute engine to database server, and try to connect from google cloud run

Tags: sql-server, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run, ssh-tunnel

So I have a SQL Server database that require me to be whitelisted to be able to access it. And I want to access it via ssh tunneling from google cloud computing.

My question is how do I do that ?. I have already tried this method

`ssh -L 127.0.0.1:1444:remote-ip:1433 user@example.com -N`

on the compute engine but I still can't connect.

And please don't tell me to use VPC connector I've tried and it can only handle 100 request concurrently

Comment: Are you sure you're wanting to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server? For Microsoft SQL Servers the default MSSQLSERVER instance port number is 1433. You're trying to connect to port number 3306 which is typically for a MySQL database.

Comment: Sorry i've edited my question, `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:1444:remote-ip:1433 user@example.com -N` to this.

Comment: @Malik Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community?

Answer (score 0):

to create a ssh tunnel from anywhere to an VM you can do:
(I use this to connect to my remote mysql)

(requiere gcloud cli initialized in your local)

```
GCLOUD_PROJECT="cloud-project"
GCLOUD_USER="clouduser"
GCLOUD_VM_ZONE="vm-instance-zone"
GCLOUD_VM_HOST="vm-instance-name"
GCLOUD_VM_PORT=3306

LOCAL_PORT=3308


sudo gcloud compute ssh $GCLOUD_USER@$GCLOUD_VM_HOST \
--project=$GCLOUD_PROJECT \
--zone=$GCLOUD_VM_ZONE  \
-- -N -L $LOCAL_PORT:localhost:$GCLOUD_VM_PORT
```

- when your terminal is freeze... your tunnel is ready
- now you able to connect with 127.0.0.1:3308

Note that followed by `--` you can use args that you normally use with a pure ssh connection.